# How to distinguish between permissions who invoke security Exception and the other who do not?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have to merge an old project to lollipop version and add checking permissions at runtime in the whole files project . It is tough! But I notice that not all permissions invoke security exception. 
Should I check all the permissions who are in the manifest at runtime ? Otherwise How to distinguish between permissions who invoke security Exception and the other who do not ?

Any help or information would be appreciated ! 
Thank you in advance

Comment: you should read this post https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: Thanks for the article :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main types of permissions, Normal and Dangerous permissions.

> **Normal permissions** cover areas where your app needs to access data or
>   resources outside the app's sandbox, but where there's very little
>   risk to the user's privacy or the operation of other apps.
>
> **Dangerous permissions** cover areas where the app wants data or resources that involve the user's private information, or could
>   potentially affect the user's stored data or the operation of other
>   apps.

You need runTime permission model for all the Dangerous Permissions. Here is a list of all this Dangerous Permissions https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

from marshmallow the permission are set at run time here you get all dangerous permission u need to handle runtime

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html